# Inspect module from package in namespace

Tags: python, lxml

I am new to python and I got quite confused with imports of packages and namespaces, which is seemingly different than in Golang (or the similar nodeJS module exports).

I have the following two lines in my script:

```
from lxml import objectify
...
root = objectify.fromstring(output.encode())
```

I was trying to inspect objectify and the function `fromstring` with VS Code, but had no success, the module `objectify` couldn't even be found when I opened the `lxml` package.

So maybe this has to do with some binary modules being imported inside the package, I don't know, but I found this file:
`lxml/objectify.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` But that still leaves me wonder how to inspect the function that I want to understand.

Comment: What is the problem? What is it that you don't understand? See https://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify-module.html#fromstring

Comment: I want to inspect the source code of the fromstring() to see what data types it returns.

Comment: The source code for `fromstring()` is in a Cython file: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/objectify.pyx#L1794. See also https://lxml.de/lxml-source-howto.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I understand correctly, when you install a package via e.g. pip3, you cannot necessarily inspect the source because Cython files get compiled but normal Python code can inheret from Cython?

Comment: I don't know enough about Cython to be able to give a full explanation. But yes, things get more complicated when a library is built from more than just Python code.